# console not showing print message on server, django and uwsgi with nginx

Tags: django, debugging, nginx, logging, uwsgi

I am currently using django's back end to `post` another `api` which works correctly when I am developing locally.  But when I push it to a staging cloud server which uses uwsgi with nginx that it is not working properly anymore.  I am trying to use `print` from `django` to either save the messages into a file or somehow show it in terminal so I can know the `post response` to start `debugging` but I have no luck trying to find a way to log any `print`

I have already did something like this in the settings

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/your/file.log',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

it does work perfectly and show messages normally but how can I also `print messages` into the file too?

Can someone give me an idea or advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you already have file logging set up properly. The only thing is that it does not log prints, you have to use django's logging system. Like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# In your code

logger.debug('Some message') # Logs as debug message
logger.error('Error message') # Logs as error message
```

Your logger should log all of these to the file since it's level is DEBUG

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#using-logging